# Can I specify external upload locations in Assets with MSM via configuration file?

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager, focus-lab-master-config

I am working on a ExpressionEngine site with a lot of preexisting content in many MSM sites. Due to the need to put upload files into Amazon's S3 storage service, I am migrating all of file fields and Wygwam content to Pixel & Tonic Assets. I am using Focus Lab's Master Config.

I have added to the master config file the configuration variable mentioned in Asset's documentation:

```
$env_config['assets_source_settings'] = array(

    1 => array(
    'access_key_id'     => $s3_key,
    'secret_access_key' => $s3_secret,
    'bucket'            => $s3_bucket,
    'url_prefix'        => $s3_prefix,
    'subfolder'         => '/files/images/general/',
    ),

    ...

);
```

However when I go to the external sources page for Assets in the control panel, I do not see any of the sources listed. I can successfully use the same credentials and values by manually adding them, but I would prefer to use the configuration file instead as there are 11 sites to replicate across and quite a few upload locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create sources this way - you can only edit change configuration for already existing sources. Your best bet would be to run an SQL query to insert the rows into exp_assets_sources table and then use the configuration file.